# How to deal with async/await hell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following...

```
let user;
let room;
await (async () => {
  user = User.findOne({ room_id: data.room_id });  
  room = Room.findOne({ room_id: data.room_id }); 
})();

await console.log(user, room);
```

I have multiple database queries and I want them to be asynchronous and at the same time, I want the results to be saved into variables. I tried the code above, but once the `console.log` gets reached, neither query has been executed yet. The only way I can make it work is if I change it to the following...

```
let user = await User.findOne({ room_id: data.room_id });  
let room = await Room.findOne({ room_id: data.room_id }); 

await console.log(user, room);
```

Is there no way to make the queries perform asynchronously but finish executing before `console.log()` gets reached?

Comment: Your anonymous function does not return anything and does not contain any `await` expressions.

Comment: `The only way I can make it work is if I change it to the following...` That shouldn't work either, because the variables are populated asynchronously, `await console.log` doesn't do anything (lines below will execute synchronously), you should only try to `await` `Promises`

Comment: @Pointy If i add await expressions inside the function, doesnt that defeat the purpose of it being asynchronous?

Comment: @Bolboa: What exactly do you mean by asynchronous? It seems you're having a conceptual mismatch between your understanding and what's really happening

Comment: I think OP wants to run the `fineOne` functions in parallel, but get the results at the same time. In which case Promise.all is the solution.

Comment: @slebetman As opposed to having them execute sequentially (one after another), is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NikKyriakides sometimes `console.log` will get called before the variables are assigned. So not its not a typo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple parallel promises to finish:

```
let [user, room] = await Promise.all([
  User.findOne({ room_id: data.room_id }),
  Room.findOne({ room_id: data.room_id })
]);
```